# How to loop through character in string and still detect null char in Bash

Tags: bash, ascii

I have this function:

```
function convert_ascii_string_to_decimal {
    ascii=$1
    unset converted_result

    while IFS="" read -r -n 1 char; do
        decimal=$(printf '%d' "'$char")
        echo $decimal
        converted_result="$converted_result $decimal"
    done < <(printf %s "$ascii")
    converted_result=$(echo $converted_result | xargs) #strip leading and trailing
}
```

It is meant to take an ascii string variable, loop through every character, and concatenate the ascii decimal representation to a string. However, this while loop seems to ignore null chars, ie characters with ascii 0. I want to be able to read every single ascii there is, including null.

Answer (score 3):

To get all characters of a string as decimal number, you can use `hexdump` to parse a string:

```
 echo -e "hello \x00world" | hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%d "'
 104 101 108 108 111 32 0 119 111 114 108 100 10
```

This also works for parsing a file:

```
echo '05 04 03 02 01 00 ff' | xxd -r -ps  > file
hexdump --no-squeezing --format '1/1 "%d "' file 
5 4 3 2 1 0 255
```

`hexdump` explanation:

- options `-v` and `--no-squeezing` prints all bytes (without skipping duplicated bytes)
- options `-e` and `--format` allows giving a specific format
- format is `1/1 "%d "` which means

  - Iteration count = `1` (process the byte only once)
  - Byte count = `1` (apply this format for each byte)
  - Format = `"%d"` (convert to decimal)

Comment: your first solution gives this error:  hexdump: illegal option -- -
usage: hexdump [-bcCdovx] [-e fmt] [-f fmt_file] [-n length]
               [-s skip] [file ...]
       hd      [-bcdovx]  [-e fmt] [-f fmt_file] [-n length]
               [-s skip] [file ...]

Comment: @DailyMemes I updated the answer with using short (instead of long) option.

Comment: @olive.. could you pls add explanation

Comment: the options -v-e and the format 1/1.. why specifically 1/1

Comment: but there is a 10 at the end? I don't want the 10

Answer (score 1):

You can't store the null character in a bash variable, which is happening in your script with the `$char` variable.

I suggest using `xxd` instead of writing your own script:

```
echo -ne "some ascii text" | xxd -p
```

If we echo a null charcter:

```
$ echo -ne "\0" | xxd -p
00
```

Comment: also the problem with this is if there is no stdout, it still reads it as null char. Is it possible to detect whether there was an stdout? or is the lack of stdout represented by null?

Comment: @DailyMemes I don't understand your question about what happens "if there is no stdout". In that case, I get *nothing*, not a null. Try `cat /dev/null | xxd -p` -- that gives me no output at all. Same with @oliv's `hexdump` answer, BTW.